# Method for getting position of the cursor in web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I recently migrated from Selenium Rc to web driver i am using the method as follows `public Number getCursorPosition(String locator)` how to implement that method by using selenium web driver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You should accept the answer which you found useful.

Comment: I think there is no exact replacement of the method mentioned by you in webdriver. What do you want to do? I believe whatever you want to do can be achieved in some other manner in webdriver.

Comment: I believe this works bit differently in Selenium Webdriver.. as @Husam pointed out...there is no replacement.
But we use WebElement.sendKeys("YourText") function instead. If you want to append some text to input...you can call this function..multiple times..incase for clearing text we use WebElement.clear() function.

check this URL for more info : http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First identify the web element then use getLocation() method to get the location/position

```
  WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.name("username")).getLocation());
```